# SQL Loader is loading incorrect value

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load data from one csv file by using SQL LOADER. Loading is successful but decimal field is containing wrong value.

PSB for details:

Table Structure:

```
COL1  VARCHAR2(250 BYTE)
COL2    DATE
COL3    DATE
COL4    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
COL5    NUMBER(13,4)
```

Input File data:

```
2001501,20180801,20180831,PRE,616
2001503,20180801,20180831,PRE,616
```

SQL Loader Control File:

```
OPTIONS(MULTITHREADING=TRUE)
load data
into table ADJ9_FMV_DEVICE_TMP
WHEN SKU != '' AND EFFECTIVE_DATE != '' AND EXPIRATION_DATE != ''
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
COL1,
COL2 "to_date (SUBSTR(:COL2, 0, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')",
COL3 "to_date (SUBSTR(:COL3, 0, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')+1 - (1/24/60/60)",
COL4 "upper(:COL4)",
COL5 DECIMAL(13,4)
)
```

After loading data in table, column 5 got loaded with some other values:

```
2001501 01/AUG/2018 00:00:00    31/AUG/2018 23:59:59    PRE -363.136
2001503 01/AUG/2018 00:00:00    31/AUG/2018 23:59:59    PRE -363.136
```

I have tried couple of option for column 5 but none is working. 
Can someone help me on this.?

Comment: Oracle's SQL loader?

Comment: Yes. Oracle SQL Loader.